# how to print all nodes from a particular node

Tags: prolog

I have the following knowledge base:

```
connects(1,11,10,8).
connects(1,12,2,6).
connects(1,13,-3,-2).
connects(1,14,1,-5).
```

I have this predicates:

```
friends(Node, L):-
findall(X,(connects(Node,X,_,_);connects(X,Node,_,_)),L).
```

when i make the question ?- friends(1,L) i have this:

```
L = [11, 12, 13, 14].
```

But my goal is print a list like this:

```
L = [11,10,8,12,2,6,13,-3,-2,14,-5]
```

How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what relationship the predicate actually represents. Anyway,  you can proceed as follows:

- First, use [findall](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) to collect the data you need as a *list of lists*:

```
?- findall([X,Y,Z], connects(1,X,Y,Z), L).
L = [[11, 10, 8], [12, 2, 6], [13, -3, -2], [14, 1, -5]].
```

- After that, you can use [append](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/2) to get a flatten list:

```
?- findall([X,Y,Z], connects(1,X,Y,Z), L0), append(L0, L1).
L0 = [[11, 10, 8], [12, 2, 6], [13, -3, -2], [14, 1, -5]],
L1 = [11, 10, 8, 12, 2, 6, 13, -3, -2, 14, 1, -5].
```

Putting it all together, you can define **friends/2** as:

```
friends(Node, L1):-
   findall([X,Y,Z],
           ( connects(Node, X,Y,Z)
           ; connects(X, Node, Y,Z) ), L0),
   append(L0, L1).
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are can change the predicate. Replacing the `_`s with variables will give you the values you need. And then use `flatten/2` to turn the matrix (2D list) into a simple 1D list.

This should solve your problem.

```
friends(Node, L):-
    findall([X, Y, Z], (connects(Node, X, Y, Z)), A),
    flatten(A, L).
```

---

Example output:

```
?- friends(1, L)
L = [11, 10, 8, 12, 2, 6, 13, -3, -2, 14, 1, -5]
```